# How do you perform OAUTH2.0 Smack XMPP authentication with talk.google.com

Tags: java, oauth, xmpp, smack

I haven't been able to find documentation on how to implementation OAuth2.0 authentication using the Smack API using access tokens. The only examples I've been able to find are Facebook examples and it looks like their implementation differs quite a bit from Googles open auth.

Comment: "Openfire Smack API"? I think you meant just "Smack API".

Comment: As far as I know smack API is part of openfire, so I don't think there is anything wrong here

Comment: Nope Smack is a client API, the only relation to Openfire is that it's both hosted at igniterealtime.org and was a former project from jivesoftware.

Comment: @noobular then stop right there cuz u know nothing John Snow - Smack is smack, and Openfire is openfire. Common things between them is ingiterealtime.org and XMPP protocol

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution and its to follow the same pattern as SASLPlainAuthentication but changing the mechanism to x-oauth2 and base64 encoding the access token fetched from all the redirect chains from google.